# <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<% ResolveUrl("~/Css/test.css") %>"/>

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Error   5   ; expected  

<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<% ***ResolveUrl("~/Css/test.css");***  %>"/>
```

Do i need to give `;` over here as my solution is not still working it starts giving some other error

Comment: What did you paste the title from that had smart quotes?

Comment: **Learn the language**.  Don't ask questions whenever you get stuck because you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add an equals sign, like this:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Css/test.css") %>"/>
```

Explanation:

`<% %>` blocks insert entire statements or blocks into the generated function.  If you want to declare a variable, start a loop, or run a stand-alone statement, use a `<% %>` block.  The code in the block must be a complete statement; it gets inserted in the middle of the method.

`<%= %>` blocks evaluate an expression and print the result; use them when you want to call a method or read a variable and output the result.  The code in the block must be an expression; it turn into an argument for a method call.

Comment: You only add a `;` to a complete, standalone, statement.  Expressions are not statements and cannot have semicolons.  Since you want to print the return value of the method, you want to use an expression, so you should add an `=` and not a `;`.