# Asp.net delimiter <% replaced with &lt;% in head tag?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, delimiter, head

Maybe its a stupid question, but i'm having this issue in Visual Studio 2010:

in my Master page i've this code:

```
<head runat="server">

    <title>App Title</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="<%= App.RootPath %>Css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

for some strange reason the `<%` is changed at runtime with `&lt;%`

`<%= App.RootPath %>` works normal if put anywhere outside head tag.

Anyone has never experienced this and resolved?

UPDATE:

If i put off runat="server" in head tag, it works. But i need it.

Edit:

All of these methods work, but the problem is lack of designer support?

Comment: Check if its somehow related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874875/link-rel-stylesheet-type-text-css-href-resolveurl-css-test-css

Comment: I've read that, but it have missed the = sign, so does not apply to this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, i've found this workaroud; still searching for the reason of this behaviour.

```
<link <%= "href=" +App.RootPath +"Css/style.css" %> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 5):

The explanation for your trick:

```
<link <%= "href='" +App.RootPath +"Css/style.css'" %> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

To find the answer generate a compilation exception. Change `App.RootPath` to `App.RootPaths..`, then navigate to the source code (it will be shown in the error page). If the compiler matches something like `<link href='' rel='' >` then it will generate the code to build a corresponding `HtmlLink` instance. So this is why it parses `<%=` as a literal string and after that it encodes it.

Your trick cheats the compiler, which is not bad at all.

I believe it does the same thing for meta tags, (`HtmlMeta`)

Answer (score 2):

This should work too.

```
<link href="<%= App.RootPath + "Css/style.css" %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally use `ResolveUrl`:

```
<link href='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~Css/style.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
**problem**
 <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.kayserianadoluhaber.com.tr/haber/<%=kanonikal%>" />

**solved**
 <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.kayserianadoluhaber.com.tr/haber/<%=kanonikal+""%>" />
```

Comment: please format your answer properly and add more explanation on how it works